# Xcode / Swift | Add TopBorder to TabBar

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

Basically what I got so far is a basic TabBarController with custumized Icons. Now I would like to add a border with a certain UIColor only at the top of the TabBar as simple as possible. How do I do that?
[My tabBar so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXv73.png)

Answer (score 0):

Configure tab bar as follows:-

```
// Create a new layer which is the width of the device and with a heigh
// of 0.5px.
CALayer *topBorder = [CALayer layer];
topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.5f);

// Set the background colour of the new layer to the colour you wish to
// use for the border.
topBorder.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];

// Add the later to the tab bar's existing layer
[self.tabBar.layer addSublayer:topBorder];
self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Either subclass your tab bar and write this over there or write this as a global function.